# How can we integrate ory kratos with django+react website

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, ory

I am having a project to integrate ory kratos for auth. I don't find much of documentation on the implementation of ory with django+react website.

I have worked with jwt previously.

Does anyone know the complete working process of integrating ory with django+react application.

Answer (score 0):

See this community example:
https://github.com/ory/examples/tree/master/django-ory-cloud
There are also a bunch of examples for react here:
https://www.ory.sh/docs/examples

Comment: Do we need any change in settings file in django. I don't see an implementation anywhere for ory kretos, keto, authkeeper etc etc

Comment: Hello @ArunKumar, that is correct there is no Django based quickstart for Keto/Oathkeeper etc. 
Feel free to create an issue in ory/examples if you already have an idea what you want there.